# Earthing in plastic enclosure

Tags: grounding

I'm working on a device with a plastic enclosure. It has a typical AC receptacle, a touchscreen, and some rubber/plastic buttons, everything else the user may touch is non-conductive plastic case. My question is, how should I earth this? In devices with metallic cases I've seen people earth the chassis, but that doesn't make any sense to me here. The screen "casing" is also plastic. Inside the device is mainly a motor/pump assembly at 24V and some measurement electronics and MCU operating at 5V off of non-isolated switching regulators that step-down from the 24V line. The 24V line is generated through a medically rated power supply according to IEC 60601.

Comment: It is called " double insulation". No PE.

Comment: Why does it need to be earthed?

Answer (score 1):

> Under IEC 60601-1:1988/A2:1995 this is poorly written part of the
> standard so easy to overlook.
>
> Clause 18g covers only accessible protectively earthed metal parts,
> with the typical 25A / 0.1ohm test.
>
> Clause 18f covers "other" protectively earthed metal parts and then
> goes on to describe an alternate test. The way it is written means it
> is often mistakenly considered not applicable if the alternate test is
> not applied, and the IECEE CB scheme protocol has promoted this
> mistake (many test engineers read only the protocol, not the
> standard). As such, the test of internal protectively earthed parts is
> frequently overlooked.
>
> But the correct interpretation is that for internal parts, either the
> test of 18g (i.e. 0.1ohm / 25A) or the alternate test applies. Either
> way, internal protectively earthed parts must be tested with the
> result recorded under Clause 18f.
>
> The 3rd edition, IEC 60601-1:2005 has removed the word "accessible"
> from the applicable clause, so the problem no longer exists.

Source: https://elsmar.com/elsmarqualityforum/threads/iec-60601-ground-bond-test-requirements-for-a-plastic-enclosure.54598/

So to recap, if you have earthed metal parts, then they need to not be accessible. I am assuming that this will be an issue for the touchscreen. Additionally the touchscreen should be earthed (or the boarder thereof) or it might be hard to pass the ESD test. I had issues with regulatory ESD testing and a touchscreen in the past, I ended up having to make a conductive gasket (and I had a metal case).

Comment: I am using a resistive touch screen, not capacitive. Intuitively I would think that ESD is less of an issue since there is no "electrical interaction" with the body, and the screen for resistive is nonconductive on the surface. What type of screen were you using in your application? Also many thanks for answering my question and offering the link as well.

Comment: In many regulatory safety standards an esd test is required, and they will test any points that are accessible by humans and shock it with an esd gun. 3kV will go straight through many insulators. I think ours was resistive.

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Answer (score 0):

Chassis ground may not be meaningful in safety aspects for your case. Regardless, some applications still require grounding, including automotive applications (check if I am correct, please). Meantime, if you are concerned about EMI, shielded enclosure is one effective method. Some products use conductive coating inside plastic boxes. Besides, the earth ground is good place to dissipate static charge (ESD) as well.

Answer (score 0):

you might understand adding top soil won't help,  ;)

If it is double insulated, you may not  need it.  But you can add a leakage to earth ground connection using 1Meg and any mesh screen or PCB covers if you need shielding and AC couple to earth ground also suppressed EMI.

There are std practices for medical environments, but anything you define as 0V is ground.